# What are the major performance tricks for writing your own renderer in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, performance, optimization, rendering

Does anyone have hands-on experience on this?

EDIT: Specifically, I am talking about rendering 2D graphics directly onto one bitmap buffer.

Comment: Flash is a a vector graphics renderer. What exactly do yo mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you are talking about 2D drawing?

If so, then only one piece of advice is necessary. Instead of using MovieClips, you will have a phenomenal speed increase from prerendering your content into `BitmapData` instances and then using `copyPixels` to draw them to the screen surface.

You won't get any speed increase whatsoever from `draw`. Has to be `copyPixels`.

A good example of this at work:
http://www.electrotank.com/junk/mike/flash/copyPixel/

Comment: The reason for this is that `draw` is actually just using the Flash vector renderer to draw the object, whereas `copyPixels` is just reading and writing BitmapData.

Answer (score 2):

Using sprite sheets is a handy technique that can work well, too.